# Selected value of dropdownlist in repeater control - with predefined items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DropDownList inside a repeater control in an ASP.NET page that has predefined items. How would I go about setting the selected value of it after binding the data to the repeater control?

For example, I have this code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Communication" Value="Communcation" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Interpersonal" Value="Interpersonal" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Because the DropDownList control doesn't have a SelectedValue front-end property, I can't set it on the control level. Instead you have to use the selected property of the *list item*. What would be ideal is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboType" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Type_Of_Behavior") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Communication" Value="Communcation" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Interpersonal" Value="Interpersonal" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Unfortunately that won't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the code from Pankaj Garg (thank you!) I've managed to write up the method to select the correct value. I couldn't mark it as the answer as that answer is selecting a static value, but not one that is coming from the DB. Here's the function:

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropDownList cbo = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("cboType");
        Behaviour b = (Behaviour)e.Item.DataItem;

        for (int i = 0; i < cbo.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (b.Type_of_Behaviour == cbo.Items[i].Value)
                cbo.Items[i].Selected = true;
            else
                cbo.Items[i].Selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everybody who helped out.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me what will come in place of "Behaviour". Also what to write in place of "Type_of_Behaviour". Tried many things but unable to understand. Please tell me in general! Please.

Comment: `Behavior` is the model class that you are using, and `Type_of_Behavior` is a property of the model. So if your model name is `Foo` and your property is `Bar`, you'd replace `Behaviour`  with `Foo` and `Type_of_Behavior` with `Bar`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> At Runtime You can use `OnItemDataBound` of Repeater like below..

**Sample HTML**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="YourhandlerName" >
</asp:Repeater>
```

---

### Sample Code for `OnItemDataBound` Event handler

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropDownList DropDownID = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownID");
        int ItemNo = ((YourClassName)e.Item.DataItem).Yourproperty;
        DropDownID.Items[ItemNo].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track except it always selects the second item. I've managed to figure it out by using the code you provided and e.Item.DataItem. Since my reputation on StackOverflow is less than 100 I can't post my answer for another 6 hours. When that time is up I'll post it so it helps others. Thanks!

Comment: That would work if I was storing the index in the database. However you need to either use the DropDownList.Items.FindByValue method or iterate through all the drop down list's items and compare the values, selecting the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is part of the `ListItem` itself, not the numerous types of lists - that is, you can specify an *item* is selected by setting [`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected.aspx) on *that* item:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Interpersonal" Value="Interpersonal" Selected="True"/>
```

Comment: You can't use the selected property for dynamic data though. The items are predefined however the value that should be selected is coming from the database. In the same repeater control I have a textbox like so: <asp:TextBox ID="txtBehaviorNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Behaviour_Number") %>' />. Setting the value of it is easy, but this isn't the case with the DropDownList.

Comment: You could do an `Eval` to test `true` or not on each of the items (ugh!), or you could (more decently, I think) set it from the code-behind without clogging up the UI with logic.